How to debug rails to step through process of generating accept headers
Launching an action, the browser provide information on the accept headers, which in this probematic case renders:  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 when the desired effect if to have turbo inject text/vnd.turbo-stream.html in that place.
However, debugging this has a challenge.  Using, on rails 7.1 binding.break at the very beginning of processing by the application_controller
Started POST "/ops/aggregate_items?id=23" for ::1 at 2024-05-30 10:17:22 +0200
Processing by OpsController#aggregate_items as HTML
     5|   before_action :set_clean_host_site
[...]
     8|   def set_clean_host_site
=>   9|  binding.break

the processing format has already been set.
How can one step through that process rails has gone through to determine the processing method
(then I assume I can identify the motive for the unexpected behaviour) ?
where
<%= form_with url: aggregate_items_ops_path(id: main_container_item.id), data: { turbo: true, format: :turbo_stream } do |form| %>  is rendering
<form data-turbo="true" data-format="turbo_stream" action="/ops/aggregate_items?id=23" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

but still being interpreted as HTML processing.

you need to debug that on the frontend if you're expecting a turbo request.

You're chasing a red herring as your server has nothing to do with the generation of accept headers. That's just the client telling the server which response types it can understand. As for how Rails determines the request format that's a question with a very long answer. It's a set of heuristics that depends on the presence of an extension, the accept and content-type headers and it's determined long before the request hits your controller by ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation.

@max . that was one of the assumptions I had.  I updated the question, because all the inputs appear proper... what I want to do is step through how Rails determines that format.  How could that be accessible?

You would have to dig through the components that process the request before it hits the controller. Most of them are in ActionDispatch - use a tool like pry to dig through a stack trace. However this isn't actually going to solve your issue. Listen to @Alex.

browser is sending Accept: text/html... header that means format is HTML, there is nothing to debug on the server, it is a javascript issue. data-turbo="true" - do you have turbo turned off by default? data-format="turbo_stream" - as far as i know this does nothing.

data-format="turbo_stream" was useful in early 7.0 versions.  But even removing that element, the behaviour stays the same in falling back to HTML. No, turbo is not off; it is functioning as expected elsewhere in the app.  It appears to be some issue with the class itself... which is why I want to debug the rails process for determining the processing method.

you can check raw accept header in your controller request.accept. this is where format is determined: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3.3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb#L75-L99

Both the browser and a puts in the controller confirm text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 notwithstanding the generated HTML states <form data-turbo="true" action="/ops/aggregate_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">.  Behaviour localised to this controller. Went through reserved words & ironed out.   To no effect.  Still have no idea the steps taken by ActionDispatch

I don't really understand what you expect from ActionDispatch, it's a 100% frontend issue. Accept header isn't going to change, all you have is text/html in it, that's the format, rails doesn't modify it on the server to have turbo.

Right.  This is really the first time I dig into the innards of ActionDispatch or Turbo. turbo is clearly not injecting text/vnd.turbo-stream.html as expected default behaviour ( I believe in https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/c339144924e5632d4ef5e3a7b941b3db17d9efa3/src/core/streams/stream_message.js#L4). Since this occurs only in the limited instance, clearly the application is at fault for missing turbo's processing conditions.

check what headers turbo is setting: document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("turbo:submit-start", function(event) { console.log(event.detail.formSubmission.fetchRequest.fetchOptions.headers) })

Thanks Alex.  I will keep that handy.  This will remain filed under 'weird'. what I did: 1) fiddled around putting (format: 'turbo_stream') after the path and removed parameters form form_with declaration. That forced processing but returned the text file, without dom_id insertion. 2) removed that, put in the script... accept header was correct text/vnd.turbo-stream.html, text/html, application/xhtml+xml matters processed. [surprise] 3) Re-added params... action processed as turbo_stream. [more surprise]

This answer may appear very curious, but it is reproducible (albeit difficult to do so).
The issue observed was one of system memory (probably overflow).
The way it can be intercepted is by

running the console,
changing some method you can easily generate an error from
and subsequently debug easily
If one runs the same method and hits the same error, notwithstanding the change, reload!

If after invoking a reload of the console and the error is still invaried, system memory is shot.
Solution:
Restart computer.

Turbo sets the request's Accept header during form submission.  So you'll need to step through Turbo's execution if you're trying to debug a request header issue.  You might begin with adding an event listener for turbo:before-fetch-request globally or on the form element itself and then take a look at event.detail.fetchOptions which has a headers property.  Following that event, is turbo:submit-start. Adding an eventListener for that event will allow you to inspect the formSubmission object via event.detail.formSubmission.
Alternatively and depending on your development environment, if you have the ability to open the Turbo source code within your node_modules folder and set breakpoints or add debugger statements.  That's often the most effective way I've found to debug a Turbo issue.
That said, and based on the code you shared, I believe the attribute you're looking for is data-turbo-stream, rather than format: :turbo_stream which I've not seen before.  Though data-turbo-stream should only be necessary if your form submits with a GET request.

my js skill is unreliable and could thus be inserting more garden paths here.  Could you suggest something more specific?
